# ¿Como puede eliminar conexiones de datos en Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, .net

que tal, bueno el titulo lo dice como puedo eliminar esas conexiones:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos a todos.

Comment: En el menu Vista, selecciona Explorador de Servidores. Encontraras las conexiones guardadas en el folder de datos.

Comment: en el web.config o en el app.config.

Answer (score 1):

Accede a la opcion de menu

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el lado izquiero deberia aparecer las `Data Connections`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

desde alli deberias poder administrarlas

Comment: Me sirvio, gracias

Comment: @blasterX si te sirvió, considera marcar la respuesta como aceptada para que futuros usuarios vean que la solución propuesta es correcta. Un saludo.